# CoreData saving but not changing on additional button clicks

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

I have an app Im trying to build with sleep data for sleep apnea. I successfully setup CoreData with some help and its saving the first user input from the textfields and displaying it in the log from CoreData (changing the strings to Doubles was a challenge but success). However, whenever I put another 2nd input in, it saves and displays the first input again. It won't change. What am I doing wrong? A side note, it also is not creating a unique ID for each entry for some reason. Thank you guys....you'd been awesome so far helping as Im a newbie.

SleepModel.swift

```
struct SleepModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
        var id = UUID().uuidString // ID variable
        var hoursSlept: Double // Hours slept variable
        var ahiReading: Double // AHI variable
}
```

Save function in AddEntryView.swift which is called when the button is pushed

```
 private func saveSleepModel() {
        guard let hoursSleptDouble = Double(hoursSleptString) else {
            print("hours slept is invalid")
            return
        }
        guard let ahiReadingDouble = Double(ahiReadingString) else {
            print("ahi reading is invalid")
            return
        }
        
        // Creates Sleep Model for user input & sends parameters
        var sleepModel =  SleepModel(hoursSlept: hoursSleptDouble, ahiReading: ahiReadingDouble)
        coreDataViewModel.saveRecord(sleepModel: sleepModel) {
            print("Success")
        }
    }
```

CoreDataViewModel

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class CoreDataViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
     
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    @Published var savedRecords: [SleepEntity] = []
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "SleepContainer")
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error loading contaienr - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Core data loaded successfully")
            }
        }
     fetchRecords()
    }

    
    func saveRecord(sleepModel: SleepModel, onSuccess: @escaping() -> Void) {
        let newRecord = SleepEntity(context: container.viewContext)
        newRecord.hoursSlept = sleepModel.hoursSlept
        newRecord.ahiReading = sleepModel.ahiReading
        saveData(onSuccess: onSuccess)
    }
  
    func saveData(onSuccess: @escaping() -> Void) {
        do {
            try container.viewContext.save()
            fetchRecords()

            onSuccess()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error saving items: \(error)")
        }
    }
    func fetchRecords() {
            let request = NSFetchRequest<SleepEntity>(entityName: "SleepEntity")
            request.sortDescriptors = [
                   NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \SleepEntity.id, ascending: false)
               ]

            do {
                savedRecords = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
            } catch let error  {
                print("Error fetching requests - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    
}
```

Comment: The `id` property in `SleepEntity` is not set in your code. And why do you refetch the data after saving one record? Inserting the new record according to the sort order is less expensive.

Comment: ID is a UUID property in the CoreData Entity. I thought it automatically assigns for each entry in the array? And I removed the fetchRecord() that was a mistake.

Comment: But you have to append or insert the new record to/in `savedRecords` to display it. No, an UUID is not created automatically but you can tell the entity to create one on insert.

Comment: OK, im not sure how to do that. Could you possibly help or lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Each managed object has its own unique ID. You don't need an `id` property on an Entity.

Comment: How do I reset all the values of SleepModel after they are saved? Someone somewhere else recommended that for trying to solve the same values being saved each time despite changing them

Comment: Since you are creating an instance of SleepModel inside the saveSleepModel function there is nothing to reset since the object is deleted once the function exits. And the next time you call that function a new object is created.

Comment: But then why does it just display the first value I put in every time I save a new object? It will take the user input the first time, but then every time after that it uses that first value despite what is typed in the texfield

Comment: More likely an issue with your view code than your core data code.

Comment: All the view for the data is doing is calling the coredatamodel and then using text to display each record.hoursSlept etc. the other view where the data is input and saved with the function just pulls the user inputs and then puts into the sleepModel each time the button is pushed. I think it’s something with my core data coding somewhere. I know the save function on the view is working because it prints the correct values to the console despite displaying the first input values only